# Is it true that if for every $A$: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ic_i = 0 \implies b_i = c_i = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation

I am trying to prove if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, AX = 0$ for every X $\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ then $A$ must be equal to $0$. I want to do it with index notation so I did the following:

I called $C$ the matrix we get from multiplying $A$ and $X$.
$$ c_{il} = 0 = \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_{jl}$$
We know $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ so I removed the l index since its always equal to 1 and added all $c_i$ together so we find:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{m}c_i = 0 = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_{j} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}x_{j} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}  $$
This last equation is equal to the first equation since they're both equal to $0$. So we get:
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij} = 0$$
Now my question is if the following is true:
$$ a_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij} = 0 $$
$x_j$ is $a_i$ from the title, $a_{ij}$ is $b_i$ from the title and $\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}$ is $c_i$ from the title.
To me personally it seems true because $x_j$ is completely random. Am I right or does my proof need changes?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: The statement in the title is obviously wrong. You can only say that $b_i=c_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Try proving the contrapositive i.e. if $A\neq O$ then $AX\neq 0$ for some $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if $X=e_{i}$ then $AX$ gives us the $i$ - th column of $A$

Comment: Thanks, I found another post where the statement was proved with this hint, but is there no way to do it the way I tried it?

Comment: To transition between your last two equations you need to substitute $x_{j}$ such that all except one $x_{j}$ are zero or it will not be obvious, at least to most people.